# Scheduling Python script using Python CronTab on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule a python script using the python-crontab module on Windows platform. Found the following snippet to work around but having a hard time to configure. Script name `cronTest.py`:

```
from crontab import CronTab
file_cron = CronTab(tabfile='filename.tab')
mem_cron = CronTab(tab="""
* * * * * command
""")
```

Let's say, for example, I want to print date & time for ever 5 mins using the following script, named `dateTime.py`:

```
import datetime
with open('dateInfo.txt','a') as outFile:
    outFile.write('\n' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

How do I execute `dateTime.py` and setup the cron job for every 5mins through `cronTest.py`.

Comment: Did you try putting `*/5 * * * * <PATH_TO_PYTHON> <PATH_TO_dateTime.py>` in place of `* * * * * command` and running `cronTest.py` again?

Comment: I tried replacing `command` with path to my script it didn't work, I guess I need to know what exactly I should pass to `tab` in `cron = CronTab(tab=""" */5 * * * * python <path to script>""")
my_cron=cron.new(command='python D:\Pyhon\currentDate.py')
my_cron.minute.every(1)`

Comment: You might have to specify the complete path to `python` in your crontab.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 4):

Did you run the embedded scheduler? See `Running the Scheduler` section in [the documentation](https://gitlab.com/doctormo/python-crontab):

```
tab = CronTab(tabfile='MyScripts.tab')
for result in tab.run_scheduler():
    print "This was printed to stdout by the process."
```

Because windows doesn't have a crontab process, you have to either feed your crontabs into an existing daemon or use this run_scheduler within your process to create a daemon for yourself.

Comment: I don't understand one thing: What should be the "MyScripts.tab", in the problem presented by @g1devops it will be the file  `dateTime.py` ?

Comment: Windows does have a scheduler, however - in fact, since Windows 95. I was sort of hoping to find a cross platform python scheduler, which is how I ended up here. Oh well.

Comment: If you know how it works, and how python could interact with it, perhaps it's a feature that could be added.